# Does Truecrypt use its own partition table to overcome the 2TB barrier in case of full disk encryption?

Tags: hard-drive, truecrypt

I wonder about the following.

Let's say you clean a disk using diskpart. It won't have any partition usable to the host OS. But what I can do is open up truecrypt, select wholedisk (non-system) encryption and it will encrypt and format the disk and use NTFS. Now I understand hdd's bigger than 2TB need GPT to see beyond 2TB within one partition. But when I use diskpart to check the disk. There is no GPT. Does truecrypt use it's own File-record segment system to see beyond 2Tb in this example?

Another thing. When I do create a partition in windows before wholedisk encrypting. I can align this partition with an offset to 1mb. GPT disks are misaligned with an offset of 17kb for the first GPT hidden partition but this can be corrected. In this case after correction, the truecrypt partition (whoch is aligned by windows) will be properly aligned to the physical sector properties of the disk. Which is nowawdays a multiple of 4096 bytes. But what happens in my previous example. Will truecrypt create a partition itself with a 1mb offset?
If I mount the encrypted disk and use diskpart to check this seems to be the case. But don't forget that truecrypt uses a driver that sits in between the OS and the disk. Who knows how honest this drivers is. Could it be this driver reports it's aligned to 1mb offset while it is not? Because it may have some hidden partition in gpt style with the 17kb (wrong) offset?

Comment: Truecrypt has been deprecated a long time ago. You should be using its successor Veracrypt.

Comment: Clean up your posting: "eholedisk forst" are not in my dictionnary. Otherwise you risk turning down people like me you are willing to help but are not willing to invest their time into somebody who does not care.

Comment: "whoch is aligned by windoes" I don't understand ewok speech, I am sorry.

Comment: True to be precise. Do not use your own abbreviations. "FRS" is an abbreviation I neither heard about and I consider myself quite familiar with file systems. You said: "But when I use diskpart to check the disk. There is no GPT." Don't cut full phrases into parts using ".". That is difficult to read and confusing. Put some effort into your questions. Otherwise you risk turning down people like me.

Comment: Apart from the horrible format your finding is interesting and deserves an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say you clean a disk using diskpart. It won't have any partition usable to the host OS. But what I can do is open up truecrypt, select wholedisk (non-system) encryption and it will encrypt and format the disk and use NTFS. Now I understand hdd's bigger than 2TB need GPT to see beyond 2TB within one partition. But when I use diskpart to check the disk. There is no GPT. Does truecrypt use it's own File-record segment system to see beyond 2Tb in this example?

In case of wholedisk encryption there is just one partition on your disk. Therefore there is no need for any administrative structure to lay out more than one partition. Apart from hardware restrictions of old hardware there should be no restriction to create partitions beyond 2TB because Truecrypt will only write a partition into that account, taken account the on-disc format detailed in the Truecrypt manual. The Truecrypt layout ressembles a rare layout that is called "superfloppy", a device that is directly starting with a boot sector. The only difference with Truecrypt is that the Truecrypt format contains a kind of "lead-in" of 131072 bytes. Bot as no operating has to process that unreadable lead-in, it does not matter.
Making that embedded partition available to the operating system is done by the Truecrypt driver.

> Another thing. When I do create a partition in windows before wholedisk encrypting. I can align this partition with an offset to 1mb. GPT disks are misaligned with an offset of 17kb for the first GPT hidden partition but this can be corrected. In this case after correction, the truecrypt partition (whoch is aligned by windows) will be properly aligned to the physical sector properties of the disk. Which is nowawdays a multiple of 4096 bytes. But what happens in my previous example. Will truecrypt create a partition itself with a 1mb offset? If I mount the encrypted disk and use diskpart to check this seems to be the case.

No, Truecrypt does not create a special alignment when doing whole-disc encryption. Alignment is a byproduct of the Truecrypt on-disc layout. The fact that the Truecrypt reserves 131072 which is a power of 2 and multiple of 4096 ensures alignment for all currently existing sector sizes.

> But don't forget that truecrypt uses a driver that sits in between the OS and the disk. Who knows how honest this drivers is.

When talking about the "honesty" of its driver please check the audit documentation of Truecrypt.

> Could it be this driver reports it's aligned to 1mb offset while it is not? Because it may have some hidden partition in gpt style with the 17kb (wrong) offset?

As explained above there is no need for any particular alignment.

Please be aware that my text did not involve any tests.
To verify my statements, you could backup the sector at 131072 of your raw encrypted disc. Then you would use a hex editor to modify the same sector on the provided unencrypted device.
This write operation should completely change the raw sector even if you modified just one byte in the unencrypted sector.